# Copying files from source to destination and append destination file name

Tags: python

Trying to copy specific files, based on type,  from source directory to destination directory. I would like to rename the destination file as it copies over from source to include its parent folder (S:\folder_name - file_name.pdf). Here is what I have so far and it seems to copy the intended files but I can't figure out how to rename the destination file based on source file folder location.

```
import os
import shutil as sh

root_path = (r"S:\Colocation Information Kory.Williams@charter.com )")
dest_path = (r"C:\Users\P2187119\Documents\MSA_SO Crawl")

for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(root_path):
for f in fnames:
    if f.endswith(".pdf"):
        source_file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        dest_file_path = os.path.join(dest_path, f)
        sh.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
        print(f"{f}this is my location from pdf")
    elif f.endswith(".doc"):
        source_file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        dest_file_path = os.path.join(dest_path, f)
        sh.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
        print(f"{f} this is my location from doc")
    elif f.endswith(".docx"):
        source_file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        dest_file_path = os.path.join(dest_path, f)
        sh.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
        print(f"{f} this is my location from docx")
```

**Edit:**

I can get the following code to print the filenames how I want, but I can't figure out how to introduce copying that file to a new directory and renaming with it's directory path location.

```
import os
import shutil as sh
from pathlib import Path


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/codychandler/SyncDrive/Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )'):
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".pdf"):
        print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, f)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```py
import os
import shutil as sh
from pathlib import Path


root_path = Path("S:\\Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )")
dest_path = Path("C:\\Users\\P2187119\\Documents\\MSA_SO Crawl")


for root, _, fnames in os.walk(root_path):
    for f in fnames:
        source_file_path = Path(root, f)
        ext = source_file_path.suffix
        dest_file_path = Path(
            dest_path, f"{source_file_path.stem}_{root_path.stem}{source_file_path.suffix}"
        )
        sh.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
```

Avoid to hardcode paths in your code, it's a very bad habit, but instead use a configuration file for storing them, like json or yaml files. Moreover, pay attention to how to use backslashes when typing paths in your scripts; I have added a double backslash or you could use one single forward slash.

Then, you had to much duplicate lines in your code.

When your are dealing with paths, I suggest you to use the `pathlib` library, it will make the handling of paths a lot easier.

### EDIT

In case you want your copied file to have the full path of your root folder in their name and not just the name of the root folder, you can modify the code like this (it is necessary to remove the colon and backslash chars):

```py
import os
import shutil as sh
from pathlib import Path


root_path = Path("C:\\Users\\Blunova\\Desktop\\scripts\\python\\so\\Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )\\")
dest_path = Path("C:\\Users\\Blunova\\Desktop\\scripts\\python\\so\\P2187119\\Documents\\MSA_SO Crawl")


backslash_char = "\\"
colon_char = ":"

for root, _, fnames in os.walk(root_path):
    for f in fnames:
        source_file_path = Path(root, f)
        ext = source_file_path.suffix
        dest_file_path = Path(
            dest_path,
            f"{source_file_path.stem}"
            f"_{str(root_path.resolve()).replace(backslash_char, '_').replace(colon_char, '')}"
            f"{source_file_path.suffix}"
        )
        sh.copyfile(source_file_path, dest_file_path)
```

For instance, let's imagine that you have a file called `pdf_file.pdf`  stored in your `root_path` (with nested folders) which is:

`C:\\Users\Blunova\Desktop\scripts\python\so\Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )`

Then, if your run the code above you will get the following name for the copied file (copied from the root path
within the destination folder):

`pdf_file_C_Users_Blunova_Desktop_scripts_python_so_Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com ).pdf`

Comment: Thanks @Blunova. Unfortunately I cannot get your example script to run. Here is the error I'm getting

Comment: File "/Users/codychandler/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/Sync Structure/test6.py", line 6, in <module>
    root_path = Path("\\Users\\codychandler\\SyncDrive\\Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )")
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

Comment: Hi! You have to add the following line of code at the very beginning of your script, i.e. import `Path` from the `pathlib` library: `from pathlib import Path`. I have also edited my answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: I have added another edit to my answer in case  you want your copied file to have the full path of your root folder in their name and not just the the name of the root folder.

Comment: I think we are getting close. Is there a way to take the "source_file_path" as it's full path and not just the root directory?

Comment: to clarify, I'd like to be able to rename the destination filename with the full path of where it was found in the "root_path".

Comment: Yes, it is! I edited again the second part of my answer with an example, just copy-paste my code on your IDE and run it!

Comment: What about if the mentioned pdf file is nested several folders deep inside the root_path? Is it possible to return that path?

for example- 
pdf_file_S_Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com ) nested_folder1 nested_folder2.pdf

Comment: Yes, for sure! Just run it! For instance, I made a test on my pc with nested folders for the root path, here is the result (the name of the copied file from root to destination path):
`pdf_file_C_Users_Blunova_Desktop_scripts_python_so_Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com ).pdf`

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working for me. All the copied filenames end with `Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com ).pdf` even though the file was found 4 levels deeper inside `Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )` Also, if I haven't mentioned it already, I really appreciate your help

Comment: Raw strings are your friend when it comes to formatting things correctly: eg `r'C:\Users\P2187119\Documents\MSA_SO Crawl' == 'C:\\Users\\P2187119\\Documents\\MSA_SO Crawl'`

Comment: @codychandler It's a pleasure do not worry! Just to be sure, have you run the second snippet in my answer below the **EDIT**? I edited again the second part to make it even more clear. I run it on my pc successfully before writing the answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @blunova I can't seem to get it to work. It copies and renames them as `file_name\\Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com ).pdf` when this file was actually found in `Colocation Information (Kory.Williams@charter.com )\\CA\\ABCDCA24\\MSA\\file_name`

Comment: uhm..strange! Is the example I provided at least ok?